# Need help reviewing basic python script giving output error

Tags: python, command-line, argv

I'm making some progress but having issues with the following:

`sys.argv` output error as described below

```
 File "./test.py", line 91, in <module>
    addon_handle = int(sys.argv[1])
```

Line 91 itself says:

```py
addon_handle = int(sys.argv[1])
```

(and after the start/importing dependencies the script lists this which must be related):

```
def build_url(query):
    base_url = sys.argv[0]
    return base_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(query)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to add the full error stack trace

Comment: What is the actual error that is being displayed and how are you executing test.py? My guess is that the value sys.argv[1] isnt convertible to int and therefore you are getting an error. Check out this link: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The full error is:

 python default.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "default.py", line 94, in <module>
    addon_handle = int(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `sys.argv` gives access to 2nd command line argument. Do you start your script with two (or more) arguments? If not then it is problem